# CPU frequency is 2x the base frequency.... and fan is always 100%

Tags: windows-10, cpu, fan, task-manager

On a laptop Dell Inspiron 5584, I see the following in the task manager :

Base : CPU frequency : 1,99 Ghz
Current speed : 4,21 Ghz (and varying from 3 to 4,2 Ghz every second)

The computer is doing nothing (there is no anti virus scanning nor updates no inedrive synchro)

Is this 4gHz frequency normal ? Or Will it explode soon ?  How can I limit the frequency to improve battery time and limit fan usage. it is always at max speed for now...

[image: CPU at 4 Ghz]

[image: List of active prrocesses]

Comment: Something seems to be using a fair bit of your GPU as well, which will also contribute to fan speed.

Comment: I suggest you check the "Details" tab in Task Manager to get more information. If that’s not enough, you can also try [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the cores I believe you have the I7 version. [Source](https://www.dell.com/lt/p/inspiron-15-5584-laptop/pd)

the max clock speed for this cpu is 4.6 GHz max turbo. So this is normal behavior.

no its not going to blow up. And looking at your task manager its definitly doing something. including an anti-malware which is windows own system. You should check the bios settings to see if you can change anything regarding the power management. under windows there should be the Dell Power manager application if not deleted to see if you can improve batterly life.

Best to check dell's troubleshooting features regarding [Fans noise](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-lt/sln113205/how-to-troubleshoot-fan-issues?lang=en)